# Zend Framework 2 - Rich Components - GUI - editable datagrid, datatable, lists, forms, dialogs, tree-views, autocomplete field

Tags: user-interface, datagrid, richfaces, zend-framework2

Zend Framework 2 has implemented a lot of stuff for all the layers, but like nothing for GUI.
I am missings things like datagrids, dialogs, tree-views, autocomplete fields and all the stuff one has in JSF and Richfaces.
I thougt maybe extJS could be an alternative, but theres no production ready integration yet.

Why use ZF2 when I have to write code for hours and weeks for such simple things that should already be integrated in an enterprise ready framework ?

I spent very much time now for digging into ZF2 and I learned a lot.
But because of the missing View stuff in ZF2 I'm thinking of changing to another Framework now, after weeks of hard work.

Does someone have a better solution ?

Comment: You do realize the difference between PHP/HTML and what JavaScript offers, do you? There's static stuff available like the belowmentioned ZfcTwitterBootstrap and there is a ZfcDatagrid somewhere, too, but the RICH-Stuff still requires the JavaScript frontend - that's not the responssbility of a backend-framework!

Comment: Yes I do realize the difference. But the data has at least to be prepared for this stuff. There has to be some interface for retrieving the data for a datagrid with pagination and all one needs.

Comment: Pagination components do exist. What do you need an interface for? Datagrid displays as much data as needed, that's for you to define. DataGrid, DataTable and the likes, in all honesty that is JS and not PHP, so there should not be a PHP Solution to provide a freakin JS file. but thats just my humble opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't like to answer my own questions, but I want to close this old one and maybe it helps someone else.

At the moment I am very happy with ZfcDatagrid by ThaDafinser.

https://github.com/ThaDafinser/ZfcDatagrid/commits/master

It didn't exist when I asked the question. And as you can see in this great module, it is a lot of work to create such a component for ZF2 and as you can see, it's not just a javascript being served. There's much much more logic behind with pagination, filtering, datasources, output formatting and much more.
You don't want to do this in your controller code, because you want to reuse the grid logic and every grid instance. And you don't want all that logic on client side, because of the same reason.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at this module, you may find what you need :

https://github.com/mwillbanks/ZfcTwitterBootstrap

Also, I suggest you to have a look at the modules page :

http://modules.zendframework.com/

Comment: Thanks Tounu. The ZfcTwitterBootstrap module has some view helpers but its not what I'm looking for.
Of course I looked many many times in the ZF2 modules collection.
ZF2 datagrid was the closest thing I found for my needs.
https://github.com/odiaseo/zf2-datagrid

But i wished there was a standard way to solve these problems.
Now what if I need a kind of datatable besides a datagrid. Take another custom solution or write it myself ? There's conventions missing for this.

Comment: You should write it yourself I think. I agree with you, there isn't convention that could guide you a little bit. A lot of tutorials are deprecated due to new versions. But that's also the charm of ZF2 I think. Dig in the framework to find the best elements to build your solution, and eventually, share it with the community !

Comment: didn't know the modules.zendframework.com website...thanks Tounu